# javafx - Set not resizable for only one stage

Tags: java, javafx, scene, resizable

I would like to know, how to solve one problem.

OK. I have two scenes. I want to set not resizable to first scene, but the second one is still resizable. I don't know how to do it.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your scene can change scenes as much as you need and use the method setResizable

```
Scene scene = new Scene(bp);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.setResizable(false);
```